# NHibernate return strongly-typed IEnumerable based on Reflection.Type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a Lucene FT engine I am implementing on my NHibernate project.  One of the things I am trying to do is support regular maintenance, i.e. clean out the FT index and rebuild from the persisted entities.  I built a generic static method `PopulateIndex<T>` which can derive the type of entity, look for property attributes of full-text indexed columns, and store them to the Lucene directory.  My problem, now, is how to provide the method with a strongly-typed `IEnumerable<T>` from the NHibernate side.

```
public static void PopulateIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : class
{
    var entityType = typeof(T);
    if (!IsIndexable(entityType)) return;

    var entityName = entityType.Name;           
    var entityIdName = string.Format("{0}Id", entityName);

    var indexables = GetIndexableProperties(entityType);

    Logger.Info(i => i("Populating the Full-text index with values from the {0} entity...", entityName));
    using (var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
    using (var writer = new IndexWriter(FullTextDirectory.FullSearchDirectory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var entityIdValue = entityType.GetProperty(entityIdName).GetValue(entity).ToString();
            var doc = CreateDocument(entity, entityIdName, entityIdValue, indexables);
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
    }
    Logger.Info(i => i("Index population of {0} is complete.", entityName));
}
```

This is the method that is giving me agita:

```
public void RebuildIndices()
{
    Logger.Info(i => i("Rebuilding the Full-Text indices..."));
    var entityTypes = GetIndexableTypes();

    if (entityTypes.Count() == 0) return;
    FullText.ClearIndices();
    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        FullText.PopulateIndex(
            _Session.CreateCriteria(entityType)
            .List()
            );
    }
}
```

It seems like this would return a strongly-typed `List<T>` but it does not.  How can I get that strongly-typed list, or is there an alternative/ better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get strongly-typed list you should specify generic parameter. I can suggest two options:
Avoid reflection. I mean call `PopulateIndex` directly for each type:

```
public void RebuildIndexes()
{
    Logger.Info(i => i("Rebuilding the Full-Text indices..."));
    FullText.ClearIndices();
    FullText.PopulateIndex(LoadEntities<EntityA>());
    FullText.PopulateIndex(LoadEntities<EntityB>());
    ...
}

private IEnumerable<T> LoadEntities<T>()
{
    _Session.QueryOver<T>().List();
}
```

Or you can call PopulateIndex using reflection:

```
public void RebuildIndices()
{
    Logger.Info(i => i("Rebuilding the Full-Text indices..."));
    var entityTypes = GetIndexableTypes();

    if (entityTypes.Count() == 0) return;
    FullText.ClearIndices();
    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        var entityList = _Session.CreateCriteria(entityType).List();
        var populateIndexMethod = typeof(FullText).GetMethod("PopulateIndex", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var typedPopulateIndexMethod = populateIndexMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
        typedPopulateIndexMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { entityList });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `elementMethod` in your second example?

Comment: Sorry, it must be populateIndexMethod. Fixed it.

Comment: The entityList does not convert to the array needed by the `Invoke` method, and no Linq supports the untyped conversion.

Comment: Fixed second arg in the `Invoke` method call.

Comment: Well, it builds... When I get the rest of the framework fleshed out, I will let you know how it works.  Thanks for your help!